# Iterate through multiple months to get different data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I need to go through each day from January 2015 up until February 05th, 2020.

The following script gets me the dates for each month up until feb 05 2020:

```py
import pandas as pd
date = pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")


dates = pd.date_range(start='20150101', end='20200205', freq = "M").strftime("%Y%m%d")

print(dates)
```

Result:

```
Index(['20150131', '20150228', '20150331', '20150430', '20150531', '20150630',
       '20150731', '20150831', '20150930', '20151031', '20151130', '20151231',
       '20160131', '20160229', '20160331', '20160430', '20160531', '20160630',
       '20160731', '20160831', '20160930', '20161031', '20161130', '20161231',
       '20170131', '20170228', '20170331', '20170430', '20170531', '20170630',
       '20170731', '20170831', '20170930', '20171031', '20171130', '20171231',
       '20180131', '20180228', '20180331', '20180430', '20180531', '20180630',
       '20180731', '20180831', '20180930', '20181031', '20181130', '20181231',
       '20190131', '20190228', '20190331', '20190430', '20190531', '20190630',
       '20190731', '20190831', '20190930', '20191031', '20191130', '20191231',
       '20200131'],
      dtype='object'
```

The following script scrapes wind speed for each day in January 2015:
In my main I specify API key, startdate and enddate which is used in the URL. **I believe this is where the merge of the two scripts could take place.**

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import warnings

headers = {
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,da;q=0.7',
    'origin': 'https://www.wunderground.com',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'
}

#Here I get the relevant data, being the dates and wind speed, and add it to a seperate dataframe called dkk
def get_data(response):
    df = response.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(df["observations"])#[1]["valid_time_gmt", "wspd"]
    df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["valid_time_gmt"],unit='s')
    dkk = df.groupby(df["time"].dt.date)["wspd"].mean()
    return dkk 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    date = pd.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    api_key = "xxxxxx"
    start_date = "20150101"
    end_date = "20150131"

    urls = [
    "https://api.weather.com/v1/location/EGNV:9:GB/observations/historical.json?apiKey="+api_key+"&units=e&startDate="+start_date+"&endDate="+end_date+""
    ]

    #here I append data to dataframe and transpose it and store in df_transposed, which results in the 
    below. 
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for url in urls:  
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore' ,InsecureRequestWarning)
        res = requests.get(url, headers= headers, verify = False)
        data = get_data(res)
        df = df.append(data) 
    df_transposed = df.T
    print(df_transposed)
```

Results:

```
                 wspd
2015-01-01  24.333333
2015-01-02  18.696970
...
2015-01-30  12.121212
2015-01-31  21.575758
```

The question is:
I need to get the wind speed from January 01 2015 - February 05 2020. How can I best combine my scripts to get the desired output, which would be a two-column dataframe with dates in one and wind speed (wspd) in the second.

The desired output:

```
                 wspd
2015-01-01  24.333333
2015-01-02  18.696970
2015-01-03   8.454545
2015-01-04  10.363636
2015-01-05  11.333333
...
2020-02-04  13.5
2020-02-05  7.1
```

The wspd for the last two dates can be seen here:

```
https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/gb/darlington/EGNV/date/2020-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
s = df_transposed.index.to_series()
df_transposed= df_transposed.where((s >='2015-01-01') &(s<='2020-02-05'),'XXX')
```

**EDIT**

```
s = df_transposed.index.to_series()
df_transposed= df_transposed.where((s >=pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')) &
                                   (s<=pd.to_datetime('2020-02-05')),'XXX')
```

Comment: Gives me a TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Comment: This can be for your version of pandas, I have checked it with datetime, you just have to perform the conversion, either from the s series or from the limits. Please check section EDIT:)

Comment: New error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: For the third edit: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime' :S

Comment: For the fourth edit: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'. Did it work on yours? And what goes in to the "XXX"?

Comment: test it : `s = df_transposed.index.to_series()
df_transposed= df_transposed.where((s >=pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')) &
                                   (s<=pd.to_datetime('2020-02-05')),'XXX')` , **remove `strftime`**. I use pandas 0.25.3

Comment: Gives me a type error: TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'

Comment: Following your thinking I tried: ´´´df_transposed= df_transposed.where((s >=pd.to_datetime('20150101').strftime("%Y%m%d")) & (s<=pd.to_datetime('20200205').strftime("%Y%m%d")),'XXX')´´´ But it didn't work

Comment: Also, I am not sure your solution is what I need. How does working in the df_transposed replace the start_date and end_date in the URL?

Comment: This solution simply masks the values ​​that are not in that range and assigns them XXX. If you want not to get it you would need `.loc`. I will see what we can do with this last mistake. What is your version of pandas?

Comment: Version is 0.24.2, I can try and update and see what it gives me. Meanwhile I added the source to where the data for the last two days can be found. I don't have these numbers, but I need to scrape them. All the wdsp from 01-01-2015 to 05-02-2020